# how to fit three svg image equally in three grid col under one row

Tags: html, css, svg, bootstrap-4

It has been a month now since I work with the following issue but not succeed. I have three svg images with less difference in size and trying to fit them into one row adding them to different columns.

But unfortunately, the top text and those images are not fit equally. some get high padding top some bottom. I know the reason SVG width. I need help please.

```html
<div id="section-top-homepage">
<div class="row circular-wrap text-center">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 top15"><img alt="" data-entity-type="file" height="67" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/vision.svg" width="71" />
<h3 class="whitecolor top15">Vision</h3>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 top15"><img alt="" data-entity-type="file" height="72" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/objectives.svg" width="73" />
<h3 class="whitecolor top15">Objectives</h3>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 top15"><img alt="" data-entity-type="file" height="59" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/mission.svg" width="72" />
<h3 class="whitecolor top15">Mission</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The _padding_ you mention may be some empty space inside the svg image. Please add the svg code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alignment in your example is made tricky because each image and its corresponding text reside inside the same div. If the outer division is the grid container, the grid items are the child divs, not the images or text.

By making the `h3` tags direct children of the outer `div` container, they become grid items equivalent to the `div`s wrapping each image, giving a total of six grid items that can be arranged in three columns:

```
<div class="grid-container">

  <div class="image-container>
    <img .../>
  </div>

  <div class="image-container>
    <img .../>
  </div>

  <div class="image-container>
    <img .../>
  </div>  

  <h3 class="image-label">
  <h3 class="image-label">
  <h3 class="image-label">

</div>
```

Notice the three `h1` elements follow the three image `divs` - the six grid-items (all direct children of the grid container) will flow across the 'cells' created by the grid template specified for the grid container:

css:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
```

Because three (equal) columns are specified, the first three items (the `div` image containers) occupy the three 'cells' of the top row. The next three items (the `h3` labels) are pushed into the second row.

Each grid item can be made a `flex` container, allowing the position of the images relative to their `div` containers to be further refined. The containers themselves, including the labels, will always be aligned across the rows and down the columns.

The following working snipped applies the above principles to your example:

```css
img {
  background: yellow;
}

.container {
  background: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 3px 50px;
  padding: 5%;
}

.container>div,.container>h3{
  border: 3px solid green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="section-top-homepage">
<h2> grid items shown with green borders</h2>
<div class="row circular-wrap text-center container">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 top15"><img alt="" data-entity-type="file" height="67" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/vision.svg" width="71" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 top15"><img alt="" data-entity-type="file" height="72" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/objectives.svg" width="73" />

</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 top15"><img alt="" data-entity-type="file" height="59" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/mission.svg" width="72" />
</div>

<h3 class="whitecolor top15">Vision</h3>
<h3 class="whitecolor top15">Objectives</h3>
<h3 class="whitecolor top15">Mission</h3>
</div>
<p>The red area is a grid <i>container</i> specifying three equally spaced columns. The grid <i>items</i> are the direct children of the container (shown with green borders). 
<p>Each grid item is a <i>flex</i> container, allowing its content to be aligned and justified. The above example has the content aligned and justified to center. The content could be aligned by its baseline by changing the css <i>align-items</i> property to <i>flex-end</i></p>
<p>in addition to the grid-template, the css for the grid-container specifies the gap between items across rows and beteen rows. The left, right, top, and bottom space surrounding the grid items is specified by the padding applied to the grid container. 
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the layout as follows:

Comment: added the following line to the container still the image has space:                 
 div#top-home-sec>div, div#top-home-sec >h3 {
    border: 3px solid green;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

Comment: That's because your changes are very different to those in my answer. The **parent** element enclosing the 3 `img divs` and 3 `h3` tags has to be styled to `display: grid` and have a `grid-template-columns` pattern. You have made the **grandparent** of the divs and h3s a **flex** container. Either get rid of the `.row` and make the parent a grid or make it `.row` the grid container. Study my answer again. If you apply that structure, your content will align in two rows of three columns, as per my working snipped.

Comment: it works perfect i removed the row as well each col-md-4 has extra padding with and it was affecting the content not align. i removed those classes and now works fine. just added the following code: 
    .grid-container {
        /* background: red; */
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
        gap: 3px 50px;
        /* padding: 5%; */
      }
      
      .grid-container>div,.grid-container>h3
      {
        align-items: flex-end;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }

Answer (score 0):

I update the layout as follows but result is something like the image:

```
 <div class="container" id="top-home-sec">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 top15"><img alt="" data-entity-type="file" height="67" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/vision.svg" width="71" /></div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 top15"><img alt="" data-entity-type="file" height="72" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/objectives.svg" width="73" /></div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 top15"><img alt="" data-entity-type="file" height="59" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/mission.svg" width="72" /></div>

<h3 class="whitecolor top15">Vision</h3>

<h3 class="whitecolor top15">Objectives</h3>

<h3 class="whitecolor top15">Mission</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]